# Event Grid validation with Azure Function running nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, azure

I'm new to Azure Functions and nodejs (My background is mostly powershell).  I'm trying to setup a function that can handle Event Grid events and everything I've read says connecting the two should be easy.  However I can't seem to get past the "easy" validation step.  I created the function with the following code:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.log('Event Grid Validation.');
context.log(req.body[0])

if(req.body[0].data.validationcode){
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: {"validationResponse": req.body[0].data.validationcode}
    };
} else {
    context.res = {
    body: "Sorry no validation code found"
    };
}

context.done();

};
```

When I send requests directly to the function, I'm getting the expected results.  For example sending a request with the following body:

[{
    "id":  1234,
    "data":  {
                 "validationcode":  "Woo Validate Me Baby"
             },
    "subject":  "Please",
    "eventType":  "New Event"
}]

Works great as a stand alone request.  But Event Grid keeps kicking back the same fail message

Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"The attempt to validate the provided endpoint  failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."}

I feel like I'm making a rookie mistake here somewhere, but I can not figure out where.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Comment: My Powershell to test the Function looks like this  
  
    $endpoint = "https://<MyFunctionApp>/api/<MyFunction>"  
    $body = @"  
    [{  
    "id":  1234,  
    "data":  {  
                "validationcode":  "Woo Validate Me Baby"  
            },  
    "subject":  "Please",  
    "eventType":  "New Event"  
    }]  
    "@  
  
    $WR = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpoint -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"  
    $WR.Content  
  
With the <> values fill in correctly

Comment: for the life of me I can't get the formatting on that comment to come out right...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step demo, if you are new to it, I would suggest following the demo (even if its not in node.js just to get the idea). I believe your problem is more permissions than a coding issue.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1220389/Azure-EventGrid-Azure-Function-demo

Comment: Thanks!  I did skim over that page a few days ago.  I'll give it another look and walk it through a little slower.  I also suspect I'm getting blocked on something like a permission setting I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

GOT IT! I was being stupid

validationCode not validationcode....case sensitive argh

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.log('Event Grid Validation.');
context.log(req.body[0])
context.log(req.body[0].data.validationCode)

context.res = {
   "validationResponse": req.body[0].data.validationCode
};
context.done();
};
```

This works! Thanks for the help!